# Binding to a property of a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collections, binding

### Context

The WPF datagrid allows developers to manually bind each column to a property of the ItemsSource, like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The advantage of these column bindings is that Visual Studio will display design-time warnings if the bindings don't correspond to a property of the objects in the People collection. It will also provide a list of valid properties through intellisense.

I'm developing a different type of grid and am having trouble getting this functionality. Currently I have developed something like this:

```
<my:Grid ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <my:Column Property="Name" />
    <my:Column Property="Age" />
    <my:Column Property="Country" />
</my:Grid>
```

Internally these string based properties are looked up through type.GetProperty() at runtime.

### My Question

How can I implement property binding like in the DataGrid example? I have looked through the decompiled source of DataGrid and found that DataGridBoundColumn.Binding is of type BindingBase.

I reappropriated BindingBase into my custom grid but I'm still not getting strong typing or intellisense options, probably because BindingBase has no idea what type it applies to, but I don't see how to provide it with the context it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your implemantion of the property my:Column.Property to a Dependency Propertie. That will allow you to use Bindings, maybe that helps. But the intellisense around Binding is more a deal of the VS-XAML-designer and not your code.

```
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx

public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register(
"Property", typeof(Boolean),

);
public bool IsSpinning
{
get { return (bool)GetValue(PropertyProperty ); }
set { SetValue(PropertyProperty , value); }
}
```